# How do you add multiple maps to an image in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How would I put multiple maps in the Usemaps attribute of an image in javascript?

I would like to use a certain map in addition to a "Base map" if certain pre-requisites are fulfilled.

Comment: Show your relevant HTML and what you’ve tried with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your multiple `<area>` elements inside one single `<map>` element as illustrated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map

In fact, you cannot use multiple maps in the `usemap` attribute, only one. Check out the link above.

If you want to add a new `<area>` you can create a new area element, add properties and append it as a child to the map. Something like:

```
let newArea = document.createElement('area');
newArea.coords = //YOURCODE
newArea.href = //YOURCODE
yourBaseMap.appendChild(newArea);
```

Comment: I would like to use a certain map in addition to a "Base map" if certain pre-requisites are fulfilled.

Comment: You could use JS to dynamically add a new `<area>` to your existing `<map>` though! I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @TheTrueMizukageYagura You could also just clone all `<area>`s from both `<map>`s into a new `<map>`.

Comment: Thanks a million ^^